# How to mark nodes and insert weights in an adjacency graph?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have a graph with 12 nodes. The x and y coordinates are give as

```
xcord={154.780094065851,    302.747331652902,   348.235746943268,   959.228504576796,   1021.26721027296,   1114.13365936238,   358.208241883160,   181.741156296042,   838.759299985938,   906.502702816486,   662.579285251179,   536.372745335719};

ycord={347.543166449207,    461.536311618993,   261.753095520236,   431.778284592051,   250.920713280060,   432.113192132818,   1044.66583584371,   1044.70069210915,   1135.19457237168,   984.121301679063,   792.153882418914,   708.946190878097};
```

Also, these are the edges connecting the nodes.

```
Edges={{1,2},{1,3},{1,8},{1,11},{1,12},{2,3},{2,4},{2,7},{2,8},{2,11},{2,12},{3,4},{3,5},{3,11},{3,12},{4,5},{4,6},{4,10},{4,11},{4,12},{5,6},{5,11},{5,12},{6,10},{6,11},{6,12},{7,8},{7,9},{7,10},{7,11},{7,12},{8,9},{8,11},{8,12},{9,10},{9,11},{9,12},{10,11},{10,12},{11,12}};
```

Let's say, The weight of the edges are randomly generated.

I want to plot the graph. The nodes should be depicted as circles with the index within it. I also want to place the weight over the edges.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xy = Transpose[{xcord, ycord}];

SeedRandom[1];
ew = Round[ RandomReal[1, Length@edges], .01];

wam = SparseArray[Thread[edges -> ew], {12, 12}, Infinity];

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam, 
 VertexCoordinates -> xy, 
 PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled", 
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"]
```

[image]

**Update:** Add the option

```
VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], LightBlue]
```

to color the vertices, and the option

```
EdgeStyle -> Thread[(DirectedEdge @@@ edges) -> 
  Thread[{Thick, Arrowheads[{-Large, Large}], ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ ew}]]
```

to style edges and add arrow heads at both ends of edges

[image]

To render the edges without arrow heads, either (1) use `EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"` or  (2) add the option `DirectedEdges -> False` and replace `(DirectedEdge @@@ edges)` with  `(UndirectedEdge @@@ edges)` in `EdgeStyle -> ...`:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. The edges are not directional. we can have either (1) edges with no arrow at both ends or (2) arrows at both ends. Would you please plot both of this:

Comment: Also, I would prefer colourful plot. nodes with same colour. The edges can take different colours.

Comment: @dipaknarayanan, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was hoping.

Comment: the EdgeStyle is nor working! Braket error!

Comment: @dipak, updated with the corrected code.

Comment: thanks a lot for the update. I have another question relating to this, which I posted here...https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249450/how-to-partition-a-graph-with-optimal-number-of-groups

Comment: Instead of showing the weights along the edge, can I do like this...https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208836/ideas-for-styling-graph-nodes-with-weights?rq=1.   In my case, since the vertex have no weight, mat be the nodes can be of same size, instead the lines can be of different thickness...I just want to have a plot like the last one or the one third from the end..